# Matching substrings in fulltext search not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, indexing, sunspot-rails

In my rails application, i'm using solr search. Substring matching working fine on local server but it is matching full words on my deployment server.

**searchable block**

```
searchable do
  text :firstname, :lastname, :login, :mail
  boolean :member
  integer :status
end
```

**schema.xml** is.

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="10" side="front" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: is the schema same on both the servers ? and did you reindex your data ?

Comment: Yes, schema is same on both servers. But somehow it was not reindexing. Re-installing sunspot_rails after removing sunspot.yml and solr directory did the trick. Thanks for your comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Adding an answer here to inform you of possible undesired behavior)

FYI,
When you make changes to the `"text" fieldType` in the `schema.xml` you are changing the configuration for **every** indexed text field in your application. Sometimes this is not desired as some fields will need a custom configuration.

For example, let's say (for whatever reason) that you wanted to treat first names differently than other text fields. Let's say you wanted to add synonyms of first names. You would first create a **new `fieldType`** in your `schema.xml` called `first_name`

```
<fieldtype name="first_name" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldtype>
```

Then in the `fields` section of the `schema.xml` file, you would add two new dynamic fields

```
<dynamicField name="*_first_name"  stored="false" type="first_name" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_first_names" stored="true"  type="first_name" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
```

**NOTE: The 's' on the `dynamicField` name is to denote that it's a stored type, providing the * for the dynamic field helps with the sunspot configuration**

So in your `searchable` block, you can now do:

```
searchable do
  text :firstname, :as => :user_first_name
  text :lastname, :login, :mail
  boolean :member
  integer :status
end
```

This will now use your custom-configured `"first_name"` field.

If you wanted first_name to be a stored value (and you still wanted to use your custom configuration) you would implement your searchable block like:

```
searchable do
  text :firstname, :stored => true, :as => :user_first_names
  text :lastname, :login, :mail
  boolean :member
  integer :status
end
```